# null argument for JSONGenerator.writeStringField()

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, callout, java

Im getting the error '**null argument for JSONGenerator.writeStringField()**' when I call the below class from Visual Page.

**Visualforce Page Code:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead"   extensions="CreateSalesOrder" action="{!getRedir}">  
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Error Messages" collapsible="false" columns="1">
  <apex:pageMessages id="errorMessages" />
  <apex:outputLink value="/{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}">&lt; Return to Lead Page</apex:outputLink>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
 </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Below is the Apex Class**

```
public with sharing class CreateSalesOrder {
private Boolean Failed = false;
private Integer responseCode;  
private String leadId;
public CreateSalesOrder(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
Http h = new Http();
String url ='http://xxx.stage.com/salesforce/api';
this.leadId =  ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ID');
HttpRequest req = buildWebServiceRequest(url,  this.leadId);
HttpResponse res = invokeWebService(h,req);
System.Debug('RESPONSE: ' + res.getBody().trim());   
System.debug('HTTP Response Code: ' + res.getStatusCode());
System.debug('Response Body: ' + res.getBody());   
responseCode=res.getStatusCode();
if (res.getStatusCode()== 201){
    this.Failed =true;
}else{
    this.Failed =false;            
    } 
}    

public HttpRequest buildWebServiceRequest(String url, String ids) {
  //Build HTTP Request object
    JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);    
    gen.writeStartObject();   

    List <Lead> Leads =  [SELECT Company,FirstName,LastName, Street, City, State, PostalCode, Phone, Email FROM Lead WHERE id=:Ids];
    for(Lead c:Leads){           
        gen.writeStringField('companyName', c.Company);
        gen.writeStringField('firstName',c.FirstName);
        gen.writeStringField('lastName',c.LastName);                
    }       
        gen.writeEndObject();        
        String jsonS = gen.getAsString();

        // Sending the http body with JSON 
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint(url);
            req.setMethod('POST');
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
            req.setHeader('Accept', 'text/html');
            req.setbody(jsonS); 
            System.debug(req);
            return req;
}    

public HttpResponse invokeWebService(Http h, HttpRequest req) {
  //Invoke Web Service
   HttpResponse res = h.send(req); 
         return res;        
 }

public PageReference getRedir() {

if (!this.Failed) {
     ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Sorry.  We got ' + responseCode + ' ' + this.leadId +'  Response Code from atlas.  Please try again later.'));
  //PageReference newPage = new PageReference('http://www.google.com');
  //newPage.setRedirect(true);
  //return newPage;
  return null;
} else {
  PageReference newPage = new PageReference('http://xxx.stage.com/' + this.leadId);
  newPage.setRedirect(true);
  return newPage;
}
}
private final ApexPages.StandardController controller;
}
```

[image]

can you please let me what is the issue on above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't write a null value with the writeStringField function; instead, if the field is null, you have to use the writeNullField function.

That means your code needs to look more like:

```
Map<String, SobjectField> fieldMap = new Map<String, SobjectField> {
  'companyName' => Lead.Company, 'firstName' => Lead.FirstName, 
  'lastName' => Lead.LastName };
for(Lead c:Leads){
    for(String key: fieldMap.keyset()) {
        String value = (String)c.get(fieldMap.get(key));
        if(value == null) {
            gen.writeNullField(key);
        } else {
            gen.writeStringField(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Honestly, it'd be a lot easier to just write the code using a generic map instead:

```
String jsonS;
for(Lead c:Leads){
    jsonS = JSON.serialize(
        new Map<String, String> {
            'companyName' => c.Company,
            'firstName' => c.FirstName,
            'lastName' => c.LastName
         });
 }
```

Comment: what if you have boolean as one node?

Comment: @PranavChitrans In the first code sample, you can use: `Object value = c.get(fieldMap.get(key));
if(value == null) {
gen.writeNullField(key);
} else if(value instanceOf String) {
gen.writeStringField(key, (String)value);
} else if(value instanceOf Boolean) {
gen.writeBooleanField(key, (Boolean)value);
}` For the second example, you can change it to: `jsonS = JSON.serialize(
new Map<String, Object> {
'companyName' => c.Company,
'firstName' => c.FirstName,
'lastName' => c.LastName
});`

Comment: yes, that what i was saying, second approach is easier but also i had doubt if the json have multiple child node like {
  "id": "wer-24242",
  "timestamp": 1628601573971,
  "event_type": "ftest,
  "payload": {
    "id": "werwer4-639c-4cdb-e96-76e38cc52e13",
    "country": "DEU",
    "request_receipt_date": "2021-08-18",
    "order_comment": "TEST/Keine",
    "devices_from_partner_stock": false,
    "request_date": "2021-08-10T13:19:14+00:00"
  }
}

Comment: @PranavChitrans You use a nested map, like this: `new Map<String, Object> { 'id' => objectId, 'timestamp' => timestamp, 'event_type' => eventType, 'payload' => new Map<String, Object> { 'id' => payloadId, 'country' => country, 'request_receipt_date' => requestReceiptDate, 'order_comment' => orderComment, 'devices_from_partner_stock' =>devicesFromPartnerStock, 'requestDate' => requestDate } }`